# Magento 2 how do show cart summary in sidebar.additional

Tags: magento2, magento2.2

I need to show products my customer already have in the cart in **sidebar.additional** with name products in the **cart, qty, price** (each product), and **total cart**. Something like order summary in onepage. how i do this?